# ERROR: Checkmarx Scan Failed: No files to scan in Jenkins while CxSAST Scan

Tags: java, jenkins, checkmarx

I am trying to run Checkmarx Scan in post build section of Jenkins.
In my jenkins job steps are --> 
1st) Getting source code from SVN Connection to Checkmarx is successful.
2nd) Build code using Maven --- Step 1 and 2 is success.
But because of 3rd) step i.e CxSAST Scan while running jenkins Build getting error like - 
[Checkmarx] - [info] - No files to zip
ERROR: Checkmarx Scan Failed: No files to scan
Where we have to configure -what source file Checkmarx is going to scan as part of Jenkins Build ?
or Where we can upload source code zip in CxSAST plugin of Jenkins ..so that checkmarx can run the Scan after build.

[image]

[image]

Have attached Job configuration screen sort .
Someone please guide how to resolve this issue .Thanks !!

Comment: Did you ever figure out the solution for this? Having the same issue here.

Comment: @duyn9uyen ... still i didn't got main reason for it. What I have done here and it's checkMarx scan is working now -> we need to setup a project inside checkMarx website...there we can specify the code repository (i.e from where checkMarx can pull new code) . In Jenkins just use the same project name with correct credential it will start the CheckMarx run automatically.

Answer (score 0):

in Jenkins you would first need to configure the Source Code Management task of your job to point to your source code repository. The CxSAST Scan task then automatically picks this for processing with Checkmarx plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same problem using Bamboo, "No files to zip."

The solution is by creating a new "Source Code Checkout (Checkout from repository)" task before the CxSAST Scanning task, on the same Job.